# How can a generic type within a generic type be accessed?

Tags: java, generics, extends

Say I have an abstract class A

```
public abstract class A<T extends SomeClass, R extends SomeClass> {
...
}
```

And I have another class B

```
public class B<S extends A> {
...
}
```

How can I access T and R within B?
When I try

```
public class B<F,G,S extends A<F,G>> {
```

It gives the Error

```
error: type argument K#1 is not within bounds of type-variable K#2
public class B<F,G,S extends A<F,G>> {
                                    ^
where K#1,K#2 are type-variables:
K#1 extends Object declared in class B
K#2 extends SomeClass declared in class A
```

Comment: `class B<F, S extends A<F>>`

Comment: `class B<T extends SomeClass, R extends SomeClass, S extends A<T, R>>`

Comment: Is your question answered at this point?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Maybe you could extend the comment to an answer? I can't find a fitting duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as @JohannesKuhn doesn't post his comment as an answer:
The solution is `class B<T extends SomeClass, R extends SomeClass, S extends A<T, R>>`